# Sorting results on initial terms within a word first

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have an autocomplete dropdown that is generated based on user's input.

Now I want to order the results in such a way that results that **start with the term** should come first, and then the rest in alphabetical order.

Right now they're just sorted alphabetically in the SQL query.

[image]

So I want *Vanco...* results to come before the rest.

As you can see, the query uses `LIKE %term%` wild card select at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN COL LIKE 'term%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC,
  COL ASC
```

Comment: great and simple... pre-sort where the term matches in same front-end context, then do the rest...

Comment: Great solution, thank you. Did you come up with it just like that?

Comment: I've had similar requirements in the past :)